# How can I make useEffect not return the initial value? I keep getting empty array when I'm trying to pass an array of objects into a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to pass in an array of registered users into a component, however I can't because it always renders the initial empty array before actually rendering the correct content. I've tried using useRef and it still does not work.

```
const Home = () => {
const nav = useNavigate()

const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState({});
const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(undefined);
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {       
    const setLoggedIn = async() => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')) {

            nav('/');
        } else {
            setLoggedInUser(await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')))
        }
    }

    setLoggedIn().catch(console.error);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {

            const data = await axios.get(`${allUsersRoute}/${loggedInUser._id}`);
            setUserList(data.data);
        }

        fetchUsers().catch(console.error);
}, [loggedInUser._id])

console.log(userList);

return (
    <div id='container'>

        <div id='sidebar'>
            <div>
                <div id='home-header'>
                    <h1>DevsHelp</h1>
                </div>

                <Userlist props={userList}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )};
```

And here is the component I'm trying to render.

```
const Userlist = (props) => {

return (
        <div>
            <div id='home-header'>
                <h1>DevsHelp</h1>
            </div>

            <div id='userlist'>
                {props.map((prop) => {
                    {console.log(props.length)}
                    return (
                        <div className='user'>
                            <h3>{prop.username}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
)}
export default Userlist;
```

So basically, react returns .map is not a function, and I assume it's because the array goes in empty. I'm fairly new to React, so if anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: If it’s showing “map isn’t a function” it’s because the value isn’t something with `map`, i.e., something other than an array, empty or not. Have you logged the data? Why would a get of a user ID return an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mapping over the props object, not the `userList`.
Try to do the following:

```
const Userlist = (props) => {

return (
        <div>
            <div id='home-header'>
                <h1>DevsHelp</h1>
            </div>

            <div id='userlist'>
                // use props.users.map instead of props.map
                {props.users.map((user) => {

                    return (
                        <div className='user'>
                            <h3>{user.username}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
)}
export default Userlist;
```

and at `Home` component change the props of UserList to `users`, just to avoid confusion

```
<Userlist users={userList}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't name props for a component "props", really:

```
<Userlist props={userList}/>
```

If you really want to, then at least inside Userlist, you would need to refer to the props object:

```
props.props.map...
```

Name your props to something that make sense to you, like for example "users". Then call `props.users.map(user => {...})`

A React component can take many props. When you want to access them inside the component, you need to do so by name. In your case, you defined Userlist like this:

```
function Userlist(props){...}
```

In this case, all props would have to be accessed via the props object. You defined a `props` value inside this object when you called `<Userlist props={userList]} />`

Personally, I always destructure props when I define a new component, like this:

```
function Userlist({users}) {...}
```

As a side note, your code would have worked if you had destructured the props object: `function Userlist({props}) {...}` This would be the smallest change you could do to make the code work, I guess. But again, I would not use "props" as a name for a prop.

Comment: Wow, that actually works, I've been struggling for hours on this, thank you for the input!